# I have multiple token holders for a smart contract but it is still considering the first one

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

Considering the below code for communicating between web3js and ethereum smart contract in ropsten test net.

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(contractAddress).then(function(lastCountOfTransaction){
                    var rawTransaction = {
                        "from": contractAddress,
                        "nonce": "0x" + lastCountOfTransaction.toString(16),
                        "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(1 * 1e9), //1 can be changed to n gwei
                        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(1000000), // 1000000 can be to set to any n number
                        "to": userAddress,
                        "value": "0x0",
                        "data": ContractObject.methods.transfer(userAddress, noOfTokens).encodeABI(),
                        "chainId": chainId
                    };

                    var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
                    tx.sign(privKey);
                    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
                    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'),function(err,hash){
                        if (!err){
                            console.log(hash);
                            resolve(hash);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(err);
                            resolve(err);
                        }
                    });    
                });
```

I have multiple token holders like one is contract address which has initial value of tokens and one is token owner which has total number of supply. I want to give tokens from contract address and not from contracts owner account. Token transfer from owner account is working if we change like below

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress).then(function(lastCountOfTransaction){
                var rawTransaction = {
                    "from": myAddress,
                    "nonce": "0x" + lastCountOfTransaction.toString(16),
                    "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(1 * 1e9), //1 can be changed to n gwei
                    "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(1000000), // 1000000 can be to set to any n number
                    "to": contractAddress,
                    "value": "0x0",
                    "data": ContractObject.methods.transfer(userAddress, noOfTokens).encodeABI(),
                    "chainId": chainId
                };
```

But the above code is not working as expected. It do provide me transaction hash but in that tokens are not distributed.

Comment: Are you signing with the private key that corresponds to the `from` address?

Comment: Hey
Thanks for the reply.

Where is the private key of contract address?
I mean when I click on create button to create a contract it just return me with a contract address. Private key I have used here is of contract owner. That may be a mistake but I dont know that there is a private key for contract address too.

Comment: Contracts don't have private keys. The private key you use determines who is sending the transaction. If you want to do things from two different accounts, you'll be signing with two different private keys.

Comment: Thats what I am telling 
I have created an contract. At creation time I have given some coins to the contract. lets say 1000. Also I have given 2000 coins to owner in case if my contract needs more than 1000, than I can give it through owner account. Now at initial stage I want to send transaction from contract address. And also contract address doesn't have private key. Than how will i send tokens from contract account.

Comment: You can't send tokens from the contract's account. All you can do is call functions in the contract. So write a function in the contract that sends tokens, and then call it.

Comment: ok 
Let me see it. anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Harsh Check out the answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @smarx I understood of private key for sending transaction and private key is not available for contracts. But what if the token holder is contract itself. 

Lets take this example.
    function ERC20(
        uint8 decimals,
        uint256 totalSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        balanceOf[this] = totalSupply ** uint256(decimals);    
        name = tokenName;                                       
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                                  
    }

Comment: The contract can transfer tokens if it's programmed to do that. For example, if it has a `sendTokensSomewhere` function, then you can call that function.

Comment: Thanks @smarx for the help. You were too pretty convincing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume ERC20 token contract and check out different use cases.

First thing you need to note is that all the transfers can be done by calling the contract only, not by communicating with each other directly. Now to the use cases...

**Token Holder A -> Token Holder B :**
In this scenario, Holder A wants to transfer some tokens to Holder B. If you sign a transaction using private key of holder A, then you can simply call the `transfer` function on contract at `contractAddress`. And this is what you are doing by sending transaction in below code (which will work if `myAddress` has a balance of tokens above `noOfTokens` in contract at `contractAddress`)

```
            var rawTransaction = {
                "from": myAddress,
                "nonce": "0x" + lastCountOfTransaction.toString(16),
                "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(1 * 1e9), //1 can be changed to n gwei
                "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(1000000), // 1000000 can be to set to any n number
                "to": contractAddress,
                "value": "0x0",
                "data": ContractObject.methods.transfer(userAddress, noOfTokens).encodeABI(),
                "chainId": chainId
            };
```

**Token Holder A -> Token Holder B via Address C :**
In this scenario, Address C wants to do a transaction on behalf of Holder A. As such the standard function to call is `transferFrom`. Assuming that some sort of approval has been given from Holder A to Address C, and that `myAddress` refers to Address C, you can use the below transaction

```
            var rawTransaction = {
                "from": myAddress, // refers to Address C
                "nonce": "0x" + lastCountOfTransaction.toString(16),
                "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(1 * 1e9), //1 can be changed to n gwei
                "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(1000000), // 1000000 can be to set to any n number
                "to": contractAddress,
                "value": "0x0",
                "data": ContractObject.methods.transferFrom(userAddressA, userAddressB, noOfTokens).encodeABI(),
                "chainId": chainId
            };
```

This is as far as ERC20 goes. Refer https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard for more info.
What you are doing feels like minting, and ERC20 doesn't standardize that. 
What you can do here is that setup an owner of the contract and use a modifier like `onlyOwner` for a `mint` function in the contract. Such a `mint` function can look something like

```
function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint returns (bool) {
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    Mint(_to, _amount);
    return true;
}
```

This way you can call the `mint` function from `myAddress` (if that address is the owner) and pass the `userAddress` who should receive the tokens. You can also choose to keep an upper limit and make the tokens capped by introducing check in the `mint` function or by adding an additional modifier (like `canMint`) to it. You can check out https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#function-modifiers for more info on modifiers.

Comment: Your answer is correct but it is partial. What I wanted exactly was in above comments. But anyways thanks for answer. It cleared by concepts and gave me more confidence.

Comment: I understood of private key for sending transaction and private key is not available for contracts. But what if the token holder is contract itself. Lets take this example. function ERC20( uint8 decimals, uint256 totalSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol ) public { balanceOf[this] = totalSupply ** uint256(decimals); name = tokenName; symbol = tokenSymbol; }

Comment: Let me just clarify, you want "contract to transfer its own tokens to some other address" and you are looking for a way to achieve this. Correct?

Comment: Yes but not exactly. 
I am not saying to transfer tokens ownership to someone else or to transfer tokens in that way. Just like I want to transfer 10000 tokens to a address. Than currently it transfer from owner to that address using contract. I want to transfer from contract instead of owner. I am not assigning coins to this(means contract) instead of msg.sender(owner) in the constructor. ERC20 is a constructor

Comment: If you use your `ERC20` function as a constructor, then you are in fact assigning coins of "totalSupply" amount to the contract. Now, if I understand you correctly, then you would like to ability to transfer the "coins of contract" to some address.
If that is the case then you can modify my previously provided `mint` function and replace `totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);` with `balances[this] = balances[this].sub(_amount);` to achieve the effect.

Comment: But the bigger question is that why will you assign tokens to a contract when you can simply "mint" them (wherein you can directly issue them for any address that you would want to transfer to) using the contract!

Comment: What is the exact meaning of mint in terms of smart contract @RKaira

Comment: The process of creating a new unit of cryptocurrency is called mining or minting.

Comment: Minting is not a concept of smart contract but of cryptocurrency itself.

Comment: https://www.explaincryptocurrency.com/what-is-cryptocurrency goes in more detail.
But you will note that the newer correct term for generation and distribution of ICO specific coins is 'token generation event', however people still use the term 'mint' as that is most common and known term to describe the process.

Comment: Thanks @RKaira for the help. It is getting somewhat clear now. Thanks a lot.